# html input type password behaviour on iPhone

Tags: android, iphone, html, passwords, android-webview

I have an html pages in WebView for Android and iPhone 4. Login page. It has `<input type="password" />`. On Android device it works fine, but in iPhone when taping first time on password field the page jumps and no keyboard appear. Only on second tape there is a keyboard appear. More than it, when taping first time (iPhone) the page little resized and this changes the look of the page.

How I can prevent from jumping/resizing my page? How I can make it work same as in Android phone?

Comment: Need more info to understand what actually you are after.

Comment: Simple login form - password input and login button. When touching the password field keyboard must appear for typing. In Android it works, but in iPhone must touch it twice for getting keyboard.

Comment: Do you have any other special javascript attached to the field?

Answer (score 0):

I set up this small fiddle to test it out: http://jsfiddle.net/9keRU/

Tried it on my iphone and works just fine. Keybord pops up immediatly and zooms in on the field. Nothing unexpected. Perhaps you can show us some code, as the issue lies probably somewhere else.

Comment: I have found that some jQuery functions making fake input type "text" from input type "password" for styling it. And somehow it affects the field.